# How to send a message to a not yet subscribed for receiving messages ViewModel with MVVM Light?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I have the LoginViewModel -> MainViewModel scenario and would want to change some properties in the MainViewModel from the LoginViewModel. I know that I should use the MVVM Light Messenger broadcasting bus to send a message to MainViewModel. They are all registered in the constructor of the ViewModelLocator, but since the LoginViewModel is first, the constructor of the MainViewModel (where the registration is usually done) is not yet constructed, so the registering for messages would have not been completed at this point. What is the best practice?

Comment: How do you want to "change some properties in the MainViewModel" while the MainViewModel object is not constructed yet?

Comment: Exactly this I want to achieve. Is it possible?

Comment: I think it is not. The object of type ViewModelLocator must be created before you will have access to any of it's properties. It is independent of the MVVM Light Messenger. If the object doesn't exist, then you have access to it's static properties only.

Comment: Make these properties static

Comment: Are you only sending information to the MainViewModel upon successful login via the LoginViewModel? Is there a reason why you can't send the message you need after instantiating the MainViewModel & before disposing of the LoginViewModel (or however your view infrastructure is set up?)